# 正規表現を用いた電話番号とメールアドレスの抽出について

Tags: python

以下のコードについての質問です。「[退屈なことはpythonにやらせよう](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873117782/)」の7章を参考に、コピーしたテキストから電話番号とメールアドレスを抽出してリストにまとめるコードなのですが、

```
for groups in phone_regex.findall(text):
```

この部分では、いったいgroupsはどういったものに変化していくのでしょうか。
（`for i in range(0,100)`　の場合　`i` は　０－９９に変化する　という感じ）

また　どうして

```
phone_num = '-'.join([groups[1],groups[3],groups[5]])
```

は　`group(1)` ではなく　`groups[1]`　（ｓがつく）のでしょうか。

```
import pyperclip as pcl
import re

phone_regex =re.compile(r'''(
    (\d{1,4}|\(\d{1,4}\))           #市外局番
    (\s|-)                          #区切り
    (\d{1,4})                       #市内局番
    (\s|-)                          #区切り
    (\d{3,4})                       #加入者番号
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?  #内線番号
    )''',re.VERBOSE)

email_regex = re.compile(r'''(
    [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+       #ユーザー名
    @
    [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+          #ドメイン名
    (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})       #.after
    )''',re.VERBOSE)

#クリップボードのテキストを検索する
text = (pcl.paste())
matches = []
for groups in phone_regex.findall(text):
    phone_num = '-'.join([groups[1],groups[3],groups[5]])
    if groups[8] != '':
        phone_num += ' x' + groups[8]
    matches.append(phone_num)
for groups in email_regex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])

if len(matches)>0:
    pcl.copy('\n'.join(matches))
    print('コピーしました')
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('電話番号やメールアドレスは見つかりませんでした')
```

Answer (score 1):

`phone_regex.findall(text)`がどういうものになるかについては、結論からいうとタプルのリストになります。

例えば、textに`03-1111-2222`,`03-3333-4444`が含まれていると次のようになります。タブルは、正規表現にマッチした文字列と正規表現での8個のグループからできています。

```
[('03-1111-2222', '03', '-', '1111', '-', '2222', '', '', ''), ('03-3333-4444', '03', '-', '3333', '-', '4444', '', '', '')
```

それで、`groups`には、リストにある順番（テキストにある順番）で、正規表現にマッチ電話番号とその正規表現でのグループからできたタプルが代入されます。タプルはシーケンス型なので`groups[1]`のようにして要素を取得します。なぜ、group ではなく groups としているのかというと、正規表現でのグループを複数含むためと思われます。

詳しくは、公式ドキュメントの [re --- 正規表現操作](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/library/re.html)から、`(...)`と`re.findall`の部分を引用しておきますので、公式ドキュメントをみてください。

> (...)
>       丸括弧で囲まれた正規表現にマッチするとともに、グループの開始と終了を表します。グループの中身は以下で述べるように、マッチが実行された後で回収したり、その文字列中で以降 \number 特殊シーケンスでマッチしたりできます。リテラル '(' や ')' にマッチするには、( や ) を使うか、文字クラス中に囲みます: [(]、 [)] 。

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>     string 中の pattern による全ての重複しないマッチを、文字列のリストとして返します。 string は左から右へ走査され、マッチは見つかった順で返されます。パターン中に 1 つ以上のグループがあれば、グループのリストを返します。パターンに複数のグループがあればタプルのリストになります。空マッチは結果に含まれます。